# Searching item in List

Tags: c#

```
person[] prn = 
new person[]
{
 new person { Name = "Robert", RList = 
{new ReceipeList { NameofRecipie = "Coak" },
new ReceipeList { NameofRecipie = "Pizza" }    } },

new person { Name = "Rahim", RList = 
{ new ReceipeList { NameofRecipie = "Coak" },
new ReceipeList { NameofRecipie = "OnionBread" }} },
};
```

When searching an item

```
   ReceipeList lstr = new ReceipeList();
   lstr.NameofRecipie = "Coak";
```

using

```
var query = from lst in prn  where(lst.RList.Contains(lstr) )  select lst;
```

it did not return any result.

```
 foreach (var v in query)
 {
            Console.Write(v.Name.ToString()+" ordered   :");

            foreach(ReceipeList lst in v.RList)
            {
                Console.Write(lst.NameofRecipie.ToString()+",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't working because you're searching for a specific instance of ReceipeList (by reference).  Because of this, your query will only return values that have your specific lstr instance of ReceipeList, not a ReceipeList with the same value as the one you're specifying.

You could make this work by overriding [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) in ReceipeList, or by reworking your query to:

```
string lstr = "Coak";
var query = from lst in prn
            where lst.RList.Any(r => r.NameofRecipie == lstr)
            select lst;
```

This works because it uses the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)() method to search the ReceipeList instances by a predicate, instead of searching for a specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

Im Not sure if, but you can look at [this](http://searchdll.codeplex.com/) also, might help a little bit?